# Need assistance with "Not allowed to load local resource" issue

Tags: php, xml, resources, load, local

I'm trying to use an `xml` sheet for a project in `php` but I can't grab the values - because of some security thing I guess.

The chrome console gives me this issue:

> 'Not allowed to load local resource: file:///usr/share/nmap/nmap.xsl'

I'm wondering if I have to change some config file settings, or execute some command.

I assume it has something to do with security in accessing local files on a webserver. (There's very little help online about this!)

I'm hosting on a RiPi (raspbian). I've tried `chmod` & `chown` on the folders and files.

Comment: And i receive a blank page when i tried to load the xml sheet from the browser

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can edit your post to add additional information.

Comment: Made some formatting changes and spelling correction to improve the question's appearance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webserver is captured inside it's document root. That is not the server root directory but the "document root" set in the webserver configuration. There is no way to break out.

To the webserver, the path `/` is not the root directory of the server but the document root directory.

You are trying to access a file outside that webserver root directory.

---

I'd create a Symlink inside the document root (e.g. `/var/www/xml_files`) that points to `/usr/share/nmap`

```
ln -s /usr/share/nmap /var/www/xml_files
```

Don't forget to set `Options +FollowSymlinks` inside the apache site-configuration, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Doing as we speak; I'll let you know the outcome